# If $r, s, t \in R$, then $r \gcd (s, t)$ is associate to $\gcd(rs, rt)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I seem to be stumped on this question.  For the setting, let $R$ be an integral domain and let $r, s, t \in R$.  The question asks

> Show that $r \gcd(s, t)$ is associate to $\gcd (rs, rt)$

To start, let $d$ be some $\gcd$ of $s$ and $t$, and let $\overline{d}$ be some $\gcd$ of $rs$ and $rt$.  Since $d \mid s$ and $d \mid t$, we see that $rd \mid rs$ and $rd \mid rt$.  By definition, then $rd \mid \overline{d}$.  It is here that I am stuck.  I would like to show that $\overline{d} \mid rd$ to conclude that $rd$ and $\overline{d}$ are associate, but I cannot see how to get there.  I know that I can write $s = di$ and $t = dj$ for some $i, j \in R$.  I can also write $rt = \overline{d}n$ and $rs = \overline{d}m$ for some $m, n \in R$.  But all this gets me is $rd(i-j) = \overline{d}(m-n)$, which is not quite what I am after.  Any helpful hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show $r\mid\bar{d}$, since then using cancellation ($R$ is an integral domain) we get

$$\bar{d}\mid rs,rt\implies (\bar{d}/r)\mid s,t\implies (\bar{d}/r)\mid d\implies \bar{d}\mid rd.$$

How to show $r\mid\bar{d}$? Easy: $r\mid rs,rt\implies r\mid\bar{d}$.

Comment: What if $r$ is not a unit?

Comment: @tylerc0816 $\bar{d}/r$ is simply shorthand for the element which multiplies by $r$ to get $\bar{d}$. (This is part of why I put parentheses around it.) For example, $4/2$ is an integer even though $2$ is not a unit in $\Bbb Z$. If you want, you can think of the division as taking place in the fraction field. Alternatively, you can write "let $\bar{d}=rn$, ..." and then replace the occurrence of $\bar{d}/r$ in this answer with the letter $n$.